# rails no method error from controller in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I got a little ruby app going and I'm having trouble with one part. When I invoke the create view I use a form which passes some parameters in a post request. The only parameter I care about is the id field which I then use in the code to do something useful in the model. The problem begins when I try to take the newly created object that is formed from the CREATE request and immediately call a class method on it. The class method I have made for the object  is called create and I would like to call that method from the initialize method. When I remove the call to the create method from the initialize method everything runs smoothly which demonstrates that I've got it mostly right.

POST Request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "authenticity_token"=>"fCQw3Pegyv069jO0tZ4eY5buslyAM/r8yrG7phyoJqI=",
 "id"=>"20110806",
 "commit"=>"Create"}
```

Relevant part of Reports controller

```
  def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:id], Time.now)
  end
```

Initialize method in the Report class which is also a model and is declared as a resource in the routes file with only show, new, create as controller actions

```
class Report
  attr_accessor :date, :file_path, :time_created
  REPORT_DIR = "/home/ben/Desktop"
  date_format = "%Y%m%d"

      def initialize(report_date, timestamp)
        @date = report_date
        @file_path = REPORT_DIR+"/#{date}-orders.txt"
        @time_created = timestamp
        create unless FileTest.exist?(@file_path)
      end

def create
  @orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => { :created_at_min => "#{@date} 00:00", :created_at_max => "#{@date} 23:59", :order => "created_at DESC" })

  File.open(@file_path, 'w') { |f| 

    @orders.each do |order|

      # begin line 1
      line1 = "850   00000000000"       # standard way to start the line
      line1 += order.id.to_s            # adding the order id
      oid_len = order.id.to_s.length        # calculating the length of the   order number to
      no_spaces = 22 - oid_len      # place the appropriate number of white space
      no_spaces.times do
        line1 += " "
      end
      line1+= "PO               "       # PO + 15 spaces
      line1+= "PARTNER KEY                   "# this line is 30 chars total, readjust when partner key comes in
      line1+= "0000020552078    0001     004010                     X X401                                        P P"
      f.write (line1+"\n")          # end of line 1

      # begin line 2
      line2 = "850   BEG0020000000NE"       # standard way to start the line
      line2 += order.id.to_s            # add the order id
      no_spaces = 52 - oid_len      # calculate the necessary amount of spaces
      no_spaces.times do
        line2 += " "
      end
      line2 += order.created_at.strftime(date_format) # add the order creation date
      f.write (line2+"\n")          # end of line 2

      # begin line 3
      line3 = "850   DTM017000000"      # standard way to start the line
      line3 += "02"             # standard
      line3 += order.created_at.strftime(date_format)   # order creation date
      f.write (line3+"\n")          # end of line 3

      # begin line 4
      line4 = "850   N1 04700000"       # standard way to start the line
      line4 += "ST "                # standard Ship to qualifier with a space
      full_name = order.customer.first_name+" "+ order.customer.last_name # get the customers full name
      name_len = full_name.length       # determine the length of the name
      no_spaces = 60 - name_len             # to calculate the number of spaces needed
      line4 += full_name
      no_spaces.times do
        line4 += " "
      end
      line4 += "9 "
      line4 += order.customer.id.to_s       # add the customer ID
      f.write (line4+"\n")          # end of line 4

      # begin line 5
      line5 = "850   N3 05000000"       # standard way to start the line
      line5 += order.shipping_address.address1 # add the first line of the billing address
      f.write (line5+"\n")          # end of line 5

      # begin line 6
      line6 = "850   N4 05100000"       # standard way to start the line
      line6 += order.shipping_address.city  # add the city
      city_len = order.shipping_address.city.length # get the length to calculate the needed white space
      no_spaces = 30 - city_len
      no_spaces.times do
        line6 += " "
      end
      line6 += order.shipping_address.province_code # add the province code
      line6 += order.shipping_address.zip   # add the zip/postal code
      f.write (line6+"\n")          # end of line 6

      # begin line 7 (this line repeats per line item)
      line_no = 0               # create a line counter
      order.line_items.each do |line_item|
        line_no = line_no + 1           # increment the line number
        line7 = "850   PO108300000"     # standard way to start the line
        line7 += line_no.to_s           # add the line number to the line
        no_spaces = 20 - line_no.to_s.length    # calculate the number of spaces to append
        no_spaces.times do
          line7 += " "
        end
        no_zeroes = 16 - line_item.quantity.to_s.length # prepend the quantity with zeroes
        no_zeroes.times do
          line7 += "0"
        end
        line7 += line_item.quantity.to_s    # add the quantity to the line
        line7 += "EA"               # standard symbols
        price = '%.2f' % line_item.price    # get the price formatted ##.##
        price_len = price.to_s.length - 1   # figure out how many chars the price is - the decimal
        price.to_s =~ /([0-9]+)\.([0-9]{2})/    # convert the price to a string and break it up
        dollars = $1                # get the dollar amount from the regex
        cents   = $2                        # get the cents amount from the regex
        no_zeroes = 17 - price_len      # calculate the number of zeroes to place after the 2 / before the price
        line7 += "2"                # 2 denotes the position of the decimal in the price
        no_zeroes.times do
          line7 += "0"          # add the zeroes in the middle
        end
        line7 += dollars            # add the dollar amount
        line7 += cents          # add the cent amount
        line7 += "  PI"         # standard symbols
        line7 += line_item.sku.to_s     # add the SKU
        no_spaces = 48 - line_item.sku.to_s.length # calculate the number of spaces needed
        no_spaces.times do
          line7 += " "
        end
        line7 += "VN"               # standard symbols
        line7 += line_item.sku.to_s     # add the SKU again
        f.write (line7+"\n")            
      end                   # end of the line item

      # begin line 8
      line8 = "850   CTT204"
      no_zeroes = 12 - line_no.to_s.length
      no_zeroes.times do
        line8 += "0"
      end
      line8 += line_no.to_s
      f.write(line8+"\n")

      # begin line 9
      line9 = "850   AMT20500000TT 2000000000000058151"
      f.write(line9+"\n")

    end     # end of the order
  }     # closing the file
  @time_created = Time.now
end     # end of create method
end
```

Error report:

```
Started POST "/reports" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-08-09 02:40:17 -0400
  Processing by ReportsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"fCQw3Pegyv069jO0tZ4eY5buslyAM/r8yrG7phyoJqI=", "id"=>"20110805", "commit"=>"Create"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/report.rb:35:in `create'
  app/models/report.rb:10:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:8:in `new'
  app/controllers/reports_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Comment: Can you post your reports controller?

Comment: @Devin M thanks for taking a look, I added it.

Comment: Where do you define `REPORT_DIR`? And what does the code for it look like?

Comment: @Devin M 
even changed the report dir line to this:
    file_path = "#{REPORT_DIR}/#{date}-orders.txt"

same problem

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct project?

Comment: First, there is a missing `@` in `"/#{date}-orders.txt"`, second, your naming suggests you expect a date as first parameter, but from controller passing on the `params[:id]`

Comment: Your code does not show a method named `path` being called.  I suspect you have not posted the correct code or correct error message.

Comment: You are calling `path` on a class that is nil if you dont feel like sharing the code where you call `path` then no one here can help you.

Comment: @Rob I think that there is an error in my create method. I am posting the method now for further inspection.

Comment: @Devin M I have shared... it is just a bit convoluted since I am building a text file so a lot of the code is very simple. I think the problem is coming from the call to the shopify API

Comment: Still not seeing a call to `path`.  Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Rob I added some error code but I'm not sure it's going to help much. the line it refers me to is in the function to this line:     orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => { :created_at_min => "#{date} 00:00", :created_at_max => "#{date} 23:59", :order => "created_at DESC" })

Comment: Hmmm but your call stack does not show any Shopfy gem code.  I thought it would if that was the case....

Comment: Yeah I dont think its part of shopify, still looking for any call to `path`

Comment: @Devin M I thought NEW gets routed to initialize, I don't have a NEW method in the Report class.

Comment: @Bnjmn I dont know whats going on, are you sure this is all of the code?

Comment: @Rob please note I am building this app within the framework of a shopify app and had the code in my create method in the Report class in the controller at first and it worked fine. Moving that code into the model made this problem for me it seems.

Comment: @Bnjmn that's all cool but the problem right now is the error message does not match up with the code you've posted.  Please check that `app/models/report.rb:35` is the call to `@orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find...`.  If it is, I suggest inserting some `logger.debug` messages so you can check that you are passing the values you think you are.

Comment: @Rob got the tail of the blog and posted it above, not much help again. Line 35 is still the call the Shopify::API...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the problem. Since the app is working within the framework of a shopify app the Reports controller needs an additional method to make sure the user is authenticated before requests can be made to the API. Very Shopify specific problem and I appreciate everyone for pitching in. Without your help I'd be nowhere, thanks for helping me reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another guess...

You're passing to the Shopify API dates in the format `yyyymmdd hh:mm`, but the [API documentation](http://api.shopify.com/order.html#index) asks for dates in format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm`.

Also beware your `date_format` class variable will not be visible to your instance method (suggest making it a CONSTANT).

Comment: Excellent comments, thank you Rob. Implemented both and they helped.

Answer (score 0):

Is it this:

```
@file_path = REPORT_DIR+"/#{@date}-orders.txt"
```

You may be missing the @ sign for date.

You may also want to try using the methods provided to access noon and midnight.

```
@date.midnight
@date.midnight + 12.hours # or is it - 12.hours ?
```

Comment: Actually I don't see how this may solve your error, but perhaps it may be part of the problem. I don't see path getting called from anywhere. If possible, can you tell us which line exactly is 35?

Comment: Line 35: orders = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params => { :created_at_min => "#{date} 00:00", :created_at_max => "#{date} 23:59", :order => "created_at DESC" })

Comment: "...Ruby is more forgiving than that...".  Not really.  `date` and `@date` are two different vars.

Comment: Nope sure if it will fix your problem, but I added more suggestions, I still don't know what is calling path that causes the error. If the error changes, do update us.